# Netbeans Syntax Highlighting Lag

Tags: css, performance, netbeans, syntax-highlighting

I'm working on a pretty big project that uses a CMS and whenever I'm editing a file with a lot of lines of code (especially in a CSS file), the syntax highlighting takes a couple of seconds after I'm finished typing to change colors.

Netbeans feels a lot faster than Eclipse, but why is this bug persisting.

Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: Yeah sometimes I had that issue. But since I moved all my project folders to an SSD disk, Netbeans is fast as hell.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans 7.2.1 and 7.3 Beta 2 are currently available. 7.2.1 features a number of performance enhancements. If the code highlighting speed does not improve, please open a bug.